# How do I style autoLink="web" links?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, hyperlink, styling

I have the following TextView:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/theFooBar"
          android:autoLink="web"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:text="@string/fooBar"
          android:textColor="@android:color/black"
          android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

And the string:

```
<string name="fooBar">Foo <u>bar</u>.</string>
```

This gives my black, underlined text.  What if I want blue, non-underlined text for the link (the "bar" part), but I want the rest (the "foo" part) to be black?  How could I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommended you to use WebView instead of TextView in this situation:

```
WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.theFooBar);
String str = "<font color='blue'>bar</font><font color='black'><u>foo</u></font>";
web.setBackgroundColor(0);
// It will sets the background color from white to transparent. 
web.loadData(str, "text/html", "utf8");
```

Comment: This seems to work, but how do I handle the click?  I called setOnClickListener() but my callback is never invoked when I tap the WebView.

Comment: Yeah, using a WebView may work, but it's way too much complexity just to have some text be different colors.  Especially when it comes to localization.  I ended up putting two text views next to each other.

Comment: You can use javascript to handle your click. But if all of the problem have been in that, that you have wanted to do "non-underlined text for the link (the "bar" part), but I want the rest (the "foo" part) to be black", it is best solution to use two text views. I have given you the solution wider, imagine that you must do something more than it it has been required.

Answer (score 4):

Add android:textColorLink in TextView to define text color for links